# How to fit a model to my testing set in statsmodels (python)

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am working on a logistic regression model and I am having trouble understanding how to take the model fit from my training set onto my testing set.  Sorry, I am new to python and VERY new to statsmodels..

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import cross_validation

independent_vars = phy_train.columns[3:]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(phy_train[independent_vars], phy_train['target'], test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
X_train.columns = independent_vars
X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
X_test.columns = independent_vars
y_train = pd.DataFrame(y_train)
y_train.columns = ['target']
y_test = pd.DataFrame(y_test)
y_test.columns = ['target']
logit = sm.Logit(y_train,X_train[subset],missing='drop')
result = logit.fit()
print result.summary()

y_pred = logit.predict(X_test[subset])
```

From the last line, I get this error:

> > > y_pred = logit.predict(X_test[subset])
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >             File "C:\Users\eMachine\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 378, in predict
> > >               return self.cdf(np.dot(exog, params))
> > >           ValueError: matrices are not aligned

My training and testing data set have the same number of variables so I am sure I am misunderstanding what the logit.predict() is actually doing.

Comment: Do `np.asarray(X_train[subset]).shape` and `np.asarray(X_test[subset]).shape` have the same second value?

Comment: @user333700 Yes, they do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two predict methods.

`logit` in your example is the **model instance**. The model instance doesn't know about the estimation results. The model predict has a different signature because it needs the parameters also `logit.predict(params, exog)`. This is mainly interesting for internal usage.

What you want is the predict method of the **results instance**. In your example

`y_pred = result.predict(X_test[subset])`

should give the correct results. It uses the estimated parameters in the prediction with your new test data of explanatory variables, X_test.

Calling `model.fit()` returns an instance of a results class that provides access to additional post-estimation statistics and analysis, and to prediction.